# What icon package for pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex, icon

I am trying to find icon package in PdfLatex. I found fontawesome package but it doesn't work in pdflatex which just for xelatex or lualatex.

And about error when I tried to use fontawesome in pdflatex

```
\usepackage{fontawesome}

% and using like normal
\faLink
```

[image: Add]

Comment: What makes you say that? Both fontawesome and fontawesome5 have type 1 versions of the fonts.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you post the `code` what you tried and the `error message` what you got?....

Comment: I had edited my post